# AS3 Input Textfield get text formated with \n for every new line

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, text, newline, textfield

I have a textfield where the user can type what ever he want into it.
When the user is ready typing he can hit the send button. when he does that i get the text from the multiline textfield and pass it to my backend. there is only 1 problem 
the text is formated in 1 single line, (html text is no option!) is it possible to set after every line a \n character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var st : String ="";
for (var i:int = 0; i < tf.numLines; i++) {

            var s:String = tf.getLineText(i) + "\n";
            st += s;
}
```

does the trick

Comment: It properly does not mather much in this case, but you should not append to a string. It creates a new string every time. It much faster and less memory intensiv to add the strings to an array and then join them afterwards with the Array.join() method.

Comment: You might want to look at TextField.appendText as well